# Comparing Windows 8.1 to Windows 8.1 Pro. Remote Desktop differences.

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-8.1

From reading Microsoft's [comparison page for Windows 8.1 vs. Windows 8.1 Pro](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compare), it shows that only Windows 8.1 Pro

> Enables you to host a Remote Desktop Connection on your own PC so you can connect to it when you're using a different PC.

I can already host a remote desktop connection on Windows 8.1, and I'm sure that many others have done this. So I'm not sure what Windows 8.1 Pro has that Windows 8.1 doesn't in this regard. Does Microsoft mean that Windows 8.1 Pro allows remote access for multiple user accounts, similar to Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Only servers support multiple connection, desktop OS never.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 does not support hosting Remote Desktop sessions at all, only local sessions of which one is active at a time.

Windows 8.1 Pro supports hosting one Remote Desktop session and local sessions like Windows 8.1.

Windows Server 2012 (R2) supports hosting two concurrent Remote Desktop sessions.

Windows Server 2012 (R2) with Remote Desktop Service supports hosting as many concurrent Remote Desktop sessions as you wish/are licensed for.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services